# Tensorflow, how to preserve the intermediate node value and reuse them

Tags: tensorflow

Assuming I have the following graph.
- `X3` and `Z` are the values I care about.
- `X` and `Y` are inputs. In each different. iteration, the coming values and shapes of `X` and `Y` are different, so I think they much be `placeholder`
- The circumstance is that I need to run this graph twice in different time point to get `X3` and `Z` asynchronously.

```
+---+     op: +1           op: *3
| X +------------> X_1 +-----------> X3            +---+
+---+               +                +             | Y |
                    |                |             +-+-+ 
                    |             op:add             |
                    |                |               |
                    |                |               |
                    |   op: add      v     op:add    |
                    +------------->     <------------+
                                     Z
```

**At early time point**, I get an input `X`(say `X=7` and I don't know what's `Y` is at this moment). I want to see the value of `X3`. So I execute `sess.run([X3], {X:7})`, then it returns `24` as expected.

**At later time point**, I get another input `Y`(say `Y=8`), and this time I only want to take a look at node `Z`. But the point is that I **have to** execute `sess.run([Z], {X:7, Y:8})` to get the result.

The problem is, for the later run, I have to feed `X` again to recalculate the intermediate node `X_1` and `X3`. It calculates flow `X--> X_1 --> X3` twice which hurts the efficiency.

My idea is that `X_1` and `X3` will contain values(`X_1=8`,`X3=24`) after the early run until the graph is destroyed, then I can directly leverage the instead of recalculating.

Is there a way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following doesn't solve your problem completely, but it gets away with feeding `X` again:

```
X_temp = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32)
X = tf.placeholder_with_default(X_temp, shape=())
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=())
X_temp = tf.assign(X_temp, X)

X_1 = X_temp + 1
X3 = X_1 * 3
Z = X_1 + X3 + Y

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(X3, {X:7}))
print(sess.run(Z, {Y:8}))

#24
#40
```

Answer (score 0):

One option I would recommend is:

```
    temp_X1, temp_X3 = sess.run([X_1, X3], feed_dict={X:7})
    sess.run(Z, feed_dict={X_1:temp_X1, X3:temp_X3, Y: 8}
```

You don't need to store everything inside the `tf` graph.
See the [tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) for other options (like using a `Saver`, etc.)

**Note**: Feeding into `placeholder` is recommended by the doc, but feeding into an intermediate `Tensor` achieves your requirement the easiest.

Comment: This works fine. Directly provide values to intermediate nodes X1 and X3 will make the placeholder X become optional. But it would be better to have a way to keep data sitting in GPU instead of transferring to the CPU. Anyway, this method works fine, thank you.